# ReactJS: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a problem here when creating a date range picker with chartjs.

So the case is :

1. When the user has just logged in, the user opens the "HITAPI" page to view the chart by date.
2. Then the user filters the date according to his wishes, For example, between the 1st and 13th of February.
3. When finished selecting the date, on the web a white blank appears instead.
4. When it is reloaded again and opens the HITAPI page once again and selects a date, data will appear that corresponds to the selected date (and no white blanks appear again).

When I look at the console, it shows (**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')**).

Guess what's the error? Can you guys help me? Thank you

My Code =

```
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const defEndDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US");
  const StartDate = useRecoilValue(startDate);
  const EndDate = useRecoilValue(endDate);
  const setStartDate = useSetRecoilState(startDate);
  const setEndDate = useSetRecoilState(endDate);
  const [dataKey, setDataKey] = useState([]);

  const GetData = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await getHitApiTotal(StartDate, EndDate);
      setDataKey(result.data[1]);
      console.log(result.data[1]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const hasil = Object.values(
    dataKey.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (acc[curr["@timestamp"].split("T")[0]] == null) {
        acc[curr["@timestamp"].split("T")[0]] = {
          message: curr.message,
          timestamp: curr["@timestamp"].split("T")[0],
          count: 0,
        };
      }
      acc[curr["@timestamp"].split("T")[0]].count++;
      return acc;
    }, {})
  );

  const labels = hasil.map((item) => item.timestamp);

  const data = {
    labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: hasil.map((item) => item.count),
        borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)",
        pointRadius: 6,
        xAxisID: "x1",
      },
    ],
    options: {
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (defEndDate !== EndDate) {
      GetData();
    }
  }, [EndDate, StartDate, defEndDate]);
```

for more details, you can see the video link that I wrote below:

https://va.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_rq0olbfygO1zb5h2t.mp4

Comment: Please share a sample response from `getHitApiTotal`. It looks like your code needs some refactoring. In the meantime your could get around the white screen by using the optional chaining operator before the call to `.reduce`. i.e `dataKey?.reduce(...)`

Comment: Firstly, you need to add optional chaining for `dataKey?.reduce` and `hasil?.map`. Secondly, it's not a good idea to do some operations like `reduce` and `map` inside function body directly. Because on every re-render your `reduce` and `map` logic will be calculated. 

So, move them into the function and only call them whenever it's necessary. Also, see if you are getting `result.data` as an array and there is an item at the index `1` before accessing it. Because, that is the one which is setting `dataKey` as `undefined` and causing the TypeError.

Comment: when I change the code like this, dataKey?.reduce(...) and result?.map(...) gives new error -> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
     at Function. values (<anonymous>)
     at CallRequest